# twig form widget dynamically choose form field

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a form that dynamically generates fields based on the entities in my database (my entities are courses). For each new course, it adds a form field to modify it's sort order. My question is, how can I dynamically show these individual form fields in my table of courses?

My form logic:

```
foreach ($entities as $id => $course) { //$id key included to show you courses key value

  $formBuilder->add($course->getId(), 'text', array(
      'data' => $course->getsortOrder(),
      'label' => false,
      'attr' => array('class' => 'sort' /*, 'style' => 'visibility:hidden;'*/ )
  ));
}
```

My jQuery that modifies the form fields:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".records_list tbody").sortable({items: "tr"},
  {stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(".sort").each(function(index) {
        $(this).val(index);
      });
    }
  });
});

 /* I tested the proper functionality of this jQuery by putting 
  <input type="text" class="sort" value="{{ entity.sortOrder }}">
  into the <td> that sort order is in. I want to replace this with 
  something like {{ form_widget(form.{entity.id}) }} */
```

I can easily put:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<td> 
{% if( entity.id == 1) %}
{{form_widget(form.1)}}          //1 is entity id
{% else if (entity.id == 2 ) %}
{{form_widget(form.2)}}          //2 is entity id
{% else if (entity.id == 3 ) %}
{{form_widget(form.3)}}          //3 is entity id
{% endif %}
</td>
{% enfor %}
```

But that is obviously not very dynamic. You add a new course, and it breaks.

It would be nice if I could say

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<td>
{% set course = entity.id %}
{{form_widget(form.course)}}
</td>
{% endfor%}
```

but sadly that does not work.

Any insight as to how to dynamically add these form fields into my sortOrder 's is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what your are trying to do.

But, if you want to access dynamically a property onto an object or an array, you can use the [attribute Twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).

To you should try something like this in your template :

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(attribute(form, entity.id)) }}
    </td>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! BTW I am trying to make my list of entities sortable by dragging the <tr> that my course is in to a new location in the list.